# Accumulation points and distributions.

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $\{x_{j}\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\subset\Omega$ a set without accumulation points in $\Omega$. For each $j\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the multi index $\alpha_{j}\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}^{n}$ define
$$u(\varphi)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\partial^{\alpha_{j}}\varphi(x_{j}), \forall\varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega).$$

$(a)$ Show that $u\in\mathcal{D}^{\prime}(\Omega).$

$(b)$ Show that $u\in\mathcal{D}^{\prime}_{F}$ if, and only if, exist $M>0$ such that $|\alpha_{j}|\leq M,$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}.$

$(c)$ If $u\in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}_{F}(\Omega),$ then $u\in\mathcal{D}^{\prime}_{m}(\Omega),$ where $m=\max|\alpha_{j}|.$

I did the letter (a), could someone help me with the letters $(b)$ and $(c),$ please?

Comment: What do the indices $F$ and $m$ signify?

Comment: @md2perpe $\mathcal{D}_{k}^{\prime}(\Omega)=\{u \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}(\Omega) ; \text{ u has order less or equal k }\}$ and $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}_{F}(\Omega)=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{D}^{\prime}(\Omega).$

Comment: Do you understand the difference between $\mathcal{D}_F(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$? If $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$ can you express what is the order of $u$ on $K$? Could you show your work of (a)?

Comment: @md2perpe (a) Because a compact subset can only contain finitely many $x_j$ then 
$$| u(\varphi)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^k  |\partial^{\alpha_j}\varphi(x_j)| \leq  \sum_{j=1}^k \sup |\partial^{\alpha_j}\varphi(x_j)| $$
i.e
$$ u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega).$$

Comment: Can you give an expression for the order of $u$?

Comment: @md2perpe the order of $u$ is $k = \max |\alpha_j|?$

Comment: Almost correct. Since $j$ runs over an infinite range, it's better to write $k=\sup |\alpha_j|$. Note that $k$ might be infinite.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between $\mathcal{D}_F(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @md2perpe No, I started studying recently

Comment: The distributions in $\mathcal{D}_F(\Omega)$ have finite order, while those in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ can have infinite order.

Comment: @md2perpe Ok, I understood.

Comment: I hope that you understand enough to try to do (b) and (c) now.